# How to find arithmetic mean of elements of a set from arithmetic means of its distinct subsets?

Tags: average, means

Consider three sets $S_1$, $S_2$, and $S_3$, containing integers. Knowing arithmetic means $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$ of all elements for each of these sets, find arithmetic mean of the values of all three sets together.

Comment: **Hint :** Consider the two following situations :$$S_1 = S_2 = \lbrace 1 \rbrace \quad \text{and} \quad S_3 = \lbrace 10 \rbrace$$ and $$S_1 = S_2 = \lbrace 1 \rbrace \quad \text{and}\quad S_3 = \lbrace 9,10,11 \rbrace$$

Comment: You cannot unless the sets $S_i$ are of equal sizes (cardinalities), in which special case you can average the arithmetic means.

Comment: You need to know the (relative) sizes of the three subsets, and then (assuming they are disjoint) the overall mean is the weighted average of the three subset means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must know the size of each set (or some other information) to calculate the arithmetic mean of all of them.

Let set $S_n$ have $k_n$ elements.

The sum of elements in $S_n$ hence is $a_nk_n$.

It follows that the sum of all elements of $t$ sets is

$$\sum_{n = 1}^t a_nk_n$$

The arithmetic mean of all sets hence is

$$\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^t a_nk_n}{\displaystyle\sum_{n= 1}^t k_n}$$